# Ember Inject Service into Ember Utility

Tags: ember.js

I know Ember has a logger, but I wanted to create my own for learning purposes. I have a service called logger, and I want to be able to use this service everywhere. I have no problem injecting this service into components, controllers, and etc... I cannot figure out how to inject this service into a Utility I created without passing it through the create function. I don't want to have to pass my logger everywhere I create the utility. When I try to inject it into the object it complains about not being in a container. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you talk about a function that you statically import?

Comment: Nope, I have a bunch of utilities that are each Ember.Objects. I want them to have access to the Logger service that I created. I cannot do Ember.inject.service() on a utility.

Comment: how do you create them? If you create them with a simple `.create()` they don't know about the application and so can not access a common logger server. However if you statically import the logger this will work. Or create your utilities with the DI container or inject the owner and use `getOwner` to lookup the service.

Comment: What's the DI container, and how do I inject the owner?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, its important to understand what `Ember.inject.service` actually *does*! Its like a shorter version for this:

```
myService: Ember.computed({
  get() {
    return Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('service:myService);
  }
}),
```

So what is this `getOwner`? It gives you the owner of an Object. Most of your objects like models, controllers, components, views and so on are created by the Dependency Injection (DI) container. For a class to be available on the DI container it needs to be [registered](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_register).

Your default classes like controllers, routes, views are automatically registered by the Resolver. After registration you can [inject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#method_inject) them into other classes automatically when they are created by the container. Also into all instances created by the container the owner is injected.

Because the container itself is private, these public APIs are on the Application. getOwner also returns the application.

If you want to manually lookup an instance on the container you can use [lookup](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/ContainerProxyMixin.html#method_lookup).

For your utility class you probably use a normal `.create()` to get the object. This of course will not automatically couple it to your application, so the owner is not available. Also automatic injection will not work.

You can manually inject the owner with the [ownerInjection](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/ContainerProxyMixin.html#method_ownerInjection):

```
myClass.create(Ember.getOwner(this).ownerInjection(), {...});
```

Then `Ember.inject.service` will work because getOwner will return the injected owner.

The other thing you could do is to register your utility objects on the container and then look them up. Then the owner is automatically injected.

Comment: Hm, I just don't like how this creates a sort of coupling just to be able to have access to a service. I have to get the owner every time I create a utility. Is this considered bad ember practice?

Comment: Also a typo: `myClass.create(Ember.getOwner(this).owner.ownerInjection(), {...});` should be `myClass.create(Ember.getOwner(this).ownerInjection(), {...});`

Comment: Well, you need to couple to access a server. Probably its better to create your object not with create but by looking up the DI container. Or you don't use a service for logging but a static importable object.

Comment: I attempted ownerInjection, and it seems to be working. I can't seem to figure out how to inject the owner from an initializer though.

Comment: @Taztingo what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a Utility that uses a service. I attempted to do what you suggest by injecting the owner. This worked for the most part. I then created a factory to create instances of this Utility, but that's where I ran into the problem. I'm unsure of how to inject the owner of an Initializer in to create the instance.

Is ownerInjection bad practice, and/or Utilities not supposed to use services? I can't really find a good answer to this, but I'm having a difficult time attempting to do this.

Comment: Do you mean by "creating a factory" registering that class in the container with an initializer? If yes, if you lookup an instance the owner is automatically injected. You don't need to do anything. And yes, how you write your utility is not recommended. If its statefull write a service, if its not it should have no side effects and so not access a service directly.

Comment: Okay so if I want a Singleton object that has no state I should create a Utility, and register it using an initializer?

Comment: Utilities should be stateless functions, not objects. If you want a singleton, it has state, so use a service. If you want something custom, yes, register it and use the DI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116515/discussion-between-taztingo-and-lux).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which Ember version initiated this pattern but the Ember documentation contains the [answer to that question](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/in-depth-topics/native-classes-in-depth/#toc_using-injection) starting from v4.3:

```
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { getOwner, setOwner } from '@ember/application';

class Item {
  @service('shopping-cart') cart;

  constructor(context) {
    setOwner(this, getOwner(context));
  }

  function addToCart() {
    this.cart.add(this);
  }
}

// On any framework object...
let item = new Item(this);
item.addToCart();
```

Comment: This is perfect. This could be the modern solution for the question !!

Answer (score -2):

I hit a similar problem a little while back.

The utilities are of type Ember.Object.
So, all you have to do is inject the service into the Ember.Object class as a property.

Like this:

```
Ember.Object.reopen({
  testService:Ember.inject.service('testService')
});
```

Et Voila!Now you can literally use your service anywhere

Comment: Can you explain what you mean, or supply a code sample?

Comment: This will *not* work if the object has no owner injected.