# how can i inject a service in adapter emberjs?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to inject a service in my adapter but i'm receiving this error: "Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property on an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated via a container."

Can someone show me how can i inject a service in adapters?

```
//services/api.js

import AjaxService from 'ember-ajax/services/ajax';
import ENV from 'nfe-customer-console-v2/config/environment';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default AjaxService.extend({
    session: service(),
    host: ENV.APP.API_URL,

    headers: computed('session.authToken', {
        get() {
            let headers = {};
            const authToken = this.get('session.data.authenticated.access_token');
            if (authToken) {
                headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${authToken}`;
            }
            return headers;
        }
    })
});

//adapters/conta.js

import EmberObject from '@ember/object';
import {inject as service} from '@ember/service';

export default EmberObject.extend({
  api: service(),

  changePassword(model) {
    return this.get('api').request('/users/change_password', {
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
            oldPassword: model.oldPassword,
            newPassword: model.newPassword,
            confirmPassword: model.confirmPassword
          },
    })
  }
})

Error: "Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property on an object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated via a container."
```

Comment: what's the use case for wanting to do this? / what broader problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm using ember-ajax for requests and i have an AjaxService that add authorization header. I have to use this service for all my requests, but in adapter i can't inject the service.

Comment: can you add what code you've tried to your question? thanks! :)

Comment: thanks for the update! Are you getting any errors? if so, those'd be good to add as well. :)

Comment: thanks for adding errors!

Comment: looking at https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/customizing-adapters/

you may want to extend DS.Adapter or DS.RestAdapter so you can have some basic functionality for your `conta` resource

Comment: I don't understand why i may want to extend DS adapters if I'm not using ember-data. I've try this and i'm getting the same error. :(

Comment: oh ok, I didn't know you were not using ember-data -- how are you loading the adapter then?
adapters are an ember-data thing with how you have it?

would it make sense to move your adapter to a util and just pass the session service to it?

Comment: ok, makes sense. I just wondered if there was any possibility of doing this. thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you create the adapter instance? The probably is probably that you don't use the DI container to create your instance. If you manually `.create()` something you need to add the [`ownerInjection`](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.5/classes/ApplicationInstance/methods/ownerInjection?anchor=ownerInjection) for it to be linked to the container if you want to use `inject()`. Please see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843461/ember-inject-service-into-ember-utility).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ember Inject Service into Ember Utility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37843461/ember-inject-service-into-ember-utility)

Answer (score 0):

You can use an initializer to inject the session.
For example with 'ember-simple-auth' :

```js
// app/initializers/session.js
export function initialize(application) {
  application.inject('route', 'session', 'service:session');
  application.inject('controller', 'session', 'service:session');
  application.inject('adapter', 'session', 'service:session');
}

export default {
  name: 'session',
  after: 'ember-simple-auth',
  initialize
};
```